# A universal game

Tags: computation, economics, game-theory

In this question by "metagame" I mean a game which functions to create the rules of a sub-game.

Is there a universal metagame that would allow to create any game (including itself). Such game would be universal in a similar  sense that a universal Turing machine can simulate any Turing machine (including itself).

Comment: Maybe something like Nomic? A game with mutable rules

Comment: Maybe human society?!

Comment: @Cyril What is the formal specification of this game?

Comment: The only game that makes sense in that context is *Immortality*. Or *Perpetualis*.

Comment: What is a game? Mathematical games can be pretty wild. See this for ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy

Comment: Progressive humanity tries to partially formalize human society and natural conditions, but this is a very difficult problem, for example, there are tools for various forecasts, tools for displaying static and dynamic data using various GIS and analytical systems, there is computer modeling and games, etc. ..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't really significantly different from a universal Turing machine.  One might define a game as a Turing machine that decides who wins based on input play, and then one could create a Turing machine that takes the rules of the game (= description of the game Turing machine) as input and simulates that game.  If all the input must be generated by the players, then simply add a player that chooses the rules of the game.  That way we end up with a universal game Turing machine.

Comment: Mathematical games are way more complicated than TMs. See for ex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy as I commented above.

Comment: @user4894 Is there any proof that mathematical games cannot be modeled by Turing Machines? I didn’t see anything about that in the Wikipedia article you linked to.

Comment: I thought about that. But this is an encoding and I am looking for something that smells more like a game.

Comment: @ProQ I wondered the same thing even as I wrote it. I don't know and should not have made the claim.